# Angular.js refresh service inside a controller

Tags: controller, angularjs

i have a simple service inside a controller:

```
function OPctrl($scope, $http) {
    var s = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from etc..... &format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
  $http.jsonp(s).success(function(data) {
      $scope.titoli = data.query.results.ROWSET.ROW;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("error!")
    });
}
```

The controller bind some data in a table. I need to recall and refresh data every time i need (i.e. with a refresh button).
Can i work inside my controller ?How to ? Or i need a custom service? I am new to angular can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use a custom service. To return the data to your controller, you have three possible options:

- return a promise (using $q) and set the scope value in the promise then() function
- add a callback to your service function and set the scope value within
- let your service return an object instead of a primitive type and set it to a scope

To use your service you just inject it in your controller:

```
app.contoller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'service', function($scope, service) {
...
}]);
```

All three possibilities can be seen in action is this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/7bNAd/).

Comment: Thx, i know this fiddle already. Is a very complex example for a newbie like me.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is complex because it shows the 3 types, which causes quite some coding.

Comment: If possible, i need a more straightforward tutorial. For now i can't figure out the rules about events and controllers in an angular application.

Comment: Then I suggest you start [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started). There are also some interesting [YouTube screencasts](http://www.youtube.com/user/angularjs).